# Kivy: How Can i Adjust Button In Right Size?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

**Main screen:**

Could you please help me to fix my button problem.
Here is my Home screen.

[image]

**MY Goal:**

I want my buttons like this:
%50 smaller and have blanks between each other.
[image]

**KV codes**

```
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
<Predictor>:
    ScreenManager:
        transition: NoTransition()
        id: sm
        size: root.width, root.height
        Screen:
            name: 'homepage_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/homepage_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                Button:
                    id: underOver_button_homepage
                    on_press: root.underOver(img_underOver, sm)   
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                    Image:
                        id: img_underOver
                        source: 'images/underover_button.png'
                        allow_stretch: True
                        keep_ratio: False
                        size: self.parent.size
                        pos: underOver_button_homepage.pos       
                Button:
                    id: side_button_homepage
                    on_release: root.side(img_side, sm)
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                    Image:
                        id: img_side
                        source: 'images/side_button.png' 
                        allow_stretch: True
                        keep_ratio: False
                        size: self.parent.size
                        pos: side_button_homepage.pos
```

**What i tried and not worked**

```
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
<Predictor>:
    ScreenManager:
        transition: NoTransition()
        id: sm
        size: root.width, root.height
        Screen:
            name: 'homepage_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/homepage_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                Button:
                    size-hint: 0.50, 1 # I ADDED THIS LINE **********************
                    id: underOver_button_homepage
                    on_press: root.underOver(img_underOver, sm)   
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                    Image:
                        id: img_underOver
                        source: 'images/underover_button.png'
                        allow_stretch: True
                        keep_ratio: False
                        size: self.parent.size
                        pos: underOver_button_homepage.pos       
                Button:
                    size-hint: 0.50, 1 # I ADDED THIS LINE ******************************
                    id: side_button_homepage
                    on_release: root.side(img_side, sm)
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                    Image:
                        id: img_side
                        source: 'images/side_button.png' 
                        allow_stretch: True
                        keep_ratio: False
                        size: self.parent.size
                        pos: side_button_homepage.pos
```

I addded size-hint: 0.50, 1 to buttons but not worked.
How can i fix this.
I did't use any window config on my code. I used allow_stretch: True and                    keep_ratio: False codes for my project.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BoxLayout` tries to give all its space to its children, so it portions out its space in proportion to the `size_hint`. As long as you just use `size_hint`, the `Boxlayout` will make sure that its children fill its entire width.

An easy way to get what you want is to just put each `Button` in an `AnchorLayout`. The `AnchorLayout` centers its child by default, and the `size_hint` that you added now refers to the `AnchorLayout` size. Here is a modified version of your `kv` that does this:

```
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
<Predictor>:
    ScreenManager:
        transition: NoTransition()
        id: sm
        size: root.width, root.height
        Screen:
            name: 'homepage_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/homepage_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                AnchorLayout:
                    Button:
                        size_hint: 0.50, 1 # I ADDED THIS LINE **********************
                        id: underOver_button_homepage
                        on_press: root.underOver(img_underOver, sm)   
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                        Image:
                            id: img_underOver
                            source: 'images/underover_button.png'
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: underOver_button_homepage.pos     

                AnchorLayout:  
                    Button:
                        size_hint: 0.50, 1 # I ADDED THIS LINE ******************************
                        id: side_button_homepage
                        on_release: root.side(img_side, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                        Image:
                            id: img_side
                            source: 'images/side_button.png' 
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: side_button_homepage.pos
```